# Missing Kafka Connect Metrics using Jmx Exporter for Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect, jmx-exporter

I am trying to export kafka connect metrics. My solution consists of running the jmx exporter and exposing them at an endpoint that can then be scraped using Prometheus. Now, I am able to do that for all the metrics that I have tried, but for one set of metrics, it is not working. 
My config for export for this set of metrics looks like the following

```
  - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connector-metrics, connector=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connector_$2
    labels:
      connector: "$1"
    help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric $1"
    type: GAUGE
```

The definition for these metrics according to the official documentation looks like :

`kafka.connect:type=connector-metrics,connector="{connector}"`

I guess there is something going wrong with the pattern selection but I am not able to figure out what. Any help or pointers please !!

Comment: Hey! I'm facing the same issue! did you manage to overcome this and extract `connect-metrics` type? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the pattern you are providing for the connector part is wrong.
Can I ask for what set of metrics it is not working?

FYI: Confluent has a connector for prometheus. You can check it out.

Comment: Thanks !! I cannot really change my implementation at this stage. However, interestingly, the following pattern which is just the same works absolutely fine !! 
`
  #kafka.connect:type=connect-worker-metrics,connector="{connector}"
  - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-worker-metrics, connector=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_worker_$2
    labels:
      connector: "$1"
    help: "Kafka Connect JMX metric $1"
    type: GAUGE
`